# Check if username exists in created txt file

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, fileoutputstream

I have 3 activities named MainActivity, Register and PersonalDetails. MainActivity is where a user can login, provided that the username and password given exist or valid. If it is valid, it will then redirect to the PersonalDetails activity. Register activity is where a user can create or save new username, provided that it doesn't exist yet. If the given username already exist, then it should notify the user.

My problem is that I don't have any idea how I will check if the username is already listed in the text file created. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText uname;
EditText pword;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    pword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
}

public void login(View view){

    if (){
        //if username and password existing/valid, redirect to PersonalDetails.java
    }
    else{

    }
}
}
```

Register.java:

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText uname;
EditText pword;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    pword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
}

public void registerNew(View view){

    if(){
        //check if the username doesn't exist yet, if it doesn't, then save it to the text file
    }
    else{

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Any reason in particular that you're using a local text file for user authentication? Is this just for practice?

Comment: @nicobatu Yes. I'm just starting to learn android programming. I'm trying to practice some simple authentication.

Comment: Instead of text file you can store registered user names in SQLite. By doing so, you will also get understanding of SQLite too.

Comment: @android_dev I just want to try out this approach, and then I'll try out using SQLite,

Answer (score 0):

thats fairly easy u simply get the string u create in ur `RegisteredUsers.txt` and then search this string by using

```
ìf(!RegisteredUsersString.contains(uname.getText().toString()){
//do ur Stuff
}else{
//Username taken
}
```

Comment: What is that RegisteredUsersString?

Comment: well u got a text file there pull the whole content of the text file into that variable. i never used textfiles so i dint know how to do this but u should be using that method in ur password checking stage anyway so i guess u know hot to do it xD

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to read it from file only then it will be better to have a JSON file in assets folder. With JSON it will be easier to parse. Maintain a users JSONArray and check if the user is available in that array.

Again, this is not the correct way of doing but as you just want to do it for learning purpose then it's ok.

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't encountered JSON file yet. Could you please elaborate more or make an example of code snippet?